# Describing the nature of the intersection

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Describe the nature of the intersection between the planes with equations $$3x-2y+2z=4$$ $$-3x+2y-2z=9$$$$6x-4y+4z=8$$

Does anyone know how to solve this or how to start?

Comment: "The nature" isn't exactly precisely defined, but I think the question might be meant as (with a little help added): "Is the intersection 1) a plane, 2) a line, or 3) a point?"

Comment: In addition to Lovsovs possibilities, the answer could be 4) empty

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes my bad

Comment: @Lovsovs it can be parallel to no?

Comment: Well, equations 1 and 2 are inconsistent, and equation 3 is twice equation 1. The intersection is empty!

Comment: what does "the intersection is empty" mean

Comment: @jackkk Yep, my bad!

Comment: @Lovsovs so what would these eaqutions be

Comment: @jackkk It means there are no point(s) that intersect all the planes.

Comment: @jackkk It means: "there is no solution to the given equations".

Answer (score 3):

After rewriting a bit, we have:

\begin{align}
3x-2y+2z&=4 \\3x-2y+2z&=-9\\ 2(3x-2y+2z)&=2\cdot 4 \end{align}
The first and second equations can never be equal (since they are the same on the LHS, but differs on the RHS), and the third is just the first multiplied by $2$, so they are the same.

Hence the intersection is empty, meaning there are no points that lie in all three planes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The second equation is a scalar multiple (-1) of the first equation on the LHS, but have different constants on the RHS. This means that the planes described by these equations are parallel, and hence have no intersection.

The third equation is exactly a scalar multiple (2) of the first equation, meaning that the first and third equations form the same plane.

Therefore, there are no intersections.